# How to create a sitemap for growing site that potentially will have huge amount of URLs?

Tags: xml-sitemap

I have a website that will have potentially huge amount or URLs and I would like google bot to know about them.
So I figured I will use a sitemap index that will point on another sitemap index in a tree like way that the leaf level of the tree will point on the URLs.
But as I understand, Sitemap index can't refer to another Sitemap index.
So how can I include all my URLs without having to manually submit a new sitemap index of 50,000 links each time?

Answer (score 0):

Your sitemap index (http://yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml) should be a sitemap index of sitemaps, not sitemap indexes.

A sitemap can hold a max of 50,000 links.  That means you can have a sitemap index (sitemap.xml) of 50,000 sitemaps with 50,000 links each.  That's 2.5 billion pages.

If you don't have more than 2.5 billion pages, you only need one sitemap index that points to all of your sitemaps.

Here's an [example hierarchy](http://www.elance.com/sitemap.xml) of a sitemap that I've worked on it the past.